# Group by query of Eloquent in laravel

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

I need a query which group by hour then return data.i have a column in database with name time and the value in time column is like 13:12:43.so how can group by hour.And i need the result with order by hour.I'm trying the given query but this query return sum of all units.But i need sum of units on the base of hour like [{ hour:1,unit:0.2232},{ hour:2,unit:0.3232},..so on]

```
$response = PowerConsumption::groupBY('time')
                ->selectRaw('round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis')
                ->where(['device_id' => 2])
                    ->where('date',Carbon::now()->ToDateString)
                ->orderBy('time')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

from you controller :

```
$response = PowerConsumption::selectRaw('HOUR(time) as hour')
                ->where(['device_id' => 2])
                    ->where('date',Carbon::now()->ToDateString)
                ->orderBy('time')->get()->groupBy('hour');
$results = [];
foreach ($response as $hour => $value) {
      $results[] = ['hour'=> $hour, 'unit' => round($value->sum('unit'), 4)]
}
```

you can just do the results foreach in your view if you are not using ajax

Comment: @User101, first it group by by hour, then sum should sum that group datas